# struct.pack doesn't pack tightly

Tags: struct, binary, python-3.7, pack

I want to create and later send a 5 byte struct like this:

```
import struct
struct.pack("?i", True, 0x01020304)
>>b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03\x02\x01'
```

but as you see the 1 byte boolean get's padded by 3 bytes or filled up to an integer for some reason.
what I want as a result is:

```
>>b'\x01\x04\x03\x02\x01'
```

How can I do this and why does my solution not work? It seems to be correctly used according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760988/python-struct-error). The `=` character at the start of the format string tells the pack method to not align the data but to produce a byte string of exactly the specified length. Whether a format character allows alignment or not is specified in [this chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). Somehow I missed that.